# Can't build app on device

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, device

I got iOS application. It runs great on a simulator, but when i tried to run this app on device, debugger show me this:

```
Couldn't register com.enaza.turbomusic with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb)
```

What's happened? How should i solve this problem?

Comment: To avoid this problem, you should restart your iPhone.
And if you want to explain this problem more deeply, check the link: [Solving Simulator Bootstrap Errors](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/solving-simulator-bootstrap-errors.html)

Comment: restart your simulator clean your build and run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart your ios device. This should resolve your issue.